# Streamlit form does not execute the following - if st.form_submit_button('Save Actor'): Any idea why?

Tags: python, streamlit

Following code does not insert record into table although DB connection is working:

```
def insert_actor(fname, lname):
    print('Inserting actor: {} {}'.format(first_name, last_name))
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO actor (first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s, %s)', (fname, lname)
    conn.commit()


#form = st.form('insert_actor_form')

# Create a form with the two text input fields
def input_actor():  
    form = st.form('insert_actor_form')
    #submit_button.text = 'Save Actor'
    f_name = form.text_input('First Name')
    l_name = form.text_input('Last Name')
    if form.form_submit_button('Save Actor'):
        try:
            insert_actor(f_name, l_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

st.sidebar.button('Insert Actor', on_click=input_actor)
```

Tried to print exception above, but it seems like its not even entering the "if" validation. I tried to keep the form creation outside the input_Actor() function and it works if I do that but then it prints the form on load itself and does not wait for the insert actor button to be clicked on the sidebar.